# Translating Java code to Python

Tags: java, python, hex

I'm trying translate this Java code to Python:

```
double grades = -32.33f;
System.out.println("grades: "+grades);
double radians = Math.toRadians(grades);
System.out.println("rad: "+radians);
long radiansUp8 = 0xFFFF_FFFFL & (long)(radias * 100_000_000);
System.out.println("rad: "+radiansUp8);
String hex = Long.toHexString(radiansUp8);
System.out.println("signed to hex: "+hex);
```

I've done this:

```
import math

grades = -32.33
radians = math.radians(grades)
print radians
radians = radians * 100000000
print radians
hexValue = hex(int(radians))
print hexValue
```

But I'm not getting the same result. The Java code works fine, but in Python not. This line in particular I'm not sure how translate to Python, maybe that is the problem:

```
long radiansUp8 = 0xFFFF_FFFFL & (long)(radianes * 100_000_000);
```

The (correct) output for the Java code is:

```
grades: -32.33000183105469
rad: -0.5642649791276998
rad: 4238540799
signed to hex: fca2ffff
```

The (incorrect) output for the Python code is:

```
grades: -32.33
radians: -0.56426494717
radians: -56426494.717
signed to hex: -0x35cfffe
```

Comment: why my question has -2???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation for that line into Python is:

```
radians = 0xffffffff & long(radians * 100000000)
```

This gives (roughly!) the answer you expect:

```
>>> 0xffffffff & long(math.radians(-32.33) * 100000000)
4238540802L
```

---

What the line **does** is multiply the number of radians by 100,000,000 (giving `-56426494.71697667`), convert the result to a `long` integer (`-56426494L`) then do a *"bitwise and"* (see e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) between that and `0xffffffff`. Your current code only performs the first of these three steps.

For a simple example of what bitwise and does:

```
>>> '{:04b}'.format(int('1010', 2) & (int('0111', 2)))
'0010'
```

For each binary digit, the output digit is `1` only if both input digits are `1`.

Comment: Thanks, How can I get hexadecimal signed number? with you answer it give to me `signed to hex: 0x0`

Comment: @Tichodroma or `int`, but this makes it "look" closer to the Java

Comment: My Python 3.4 does not have a built-in `long`.

Comment: @Tichodroma no; it was [removed in 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), but (based on the `print`) the OP is using 2.x

Comment: @jonrsharpe calling `hex` I've an error and casting the argument to int to avoid the error I'm getting a `0x0` in hexadecimal output

Comment: @Hector works fine for me - `hex(4238540802L)` is `'0xfca30002L'`

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, It could be the reason??

Comment: @Hector no, I am also using 2.7 (otherwise you wouldn't see the `L` - `int` and `long` are merged in 3.x, per my comment above).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code should be translatable by the AgileUML translator:
https://github.com/eclipse/agileuml/blob/master/translators.zip

It abstracts the language-specific aspects (like Java number formats) to a language-independent form before generating Python.

Comment: I tried this, it produces the Python:   grades = 0.0
    grades = -32.33
    print("grades: " + str(grades))
    radians = 0.0
    radians = (0.017453292519943295 * grades)
    print("rad: " + str(radians))
    radiansUp8 = 0
    radiansUp8 = MathLib.bitwiseAnd(4294967295, int((radians * 100000000)))
    print("rad: " + str(radiansUp8))
    hex = ""
    hex = MathLib.decimal2hex(radiansUp8)
    print("signed to hex: " + hex)

Answer (score 0):

The results from the Python translated using AgileUML are:

grades: -32.33
rad: -0.5642649471697667
rad: 4238540802
signed to hex: FCA30002

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32498956)